# Will Apple send payment after expiration of Developer program membership

Tags: ios, developer-program

The minimum payment due in my account is $150.

Currently I have $120 proceeds in my account. My Apple Developer membership will expire by the end of this month, and I don't want to renew it.

Will Apple send payments to me after the expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Payments and Financial Reports](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Payments%20and%20Financial%20Reports_View%20payments%20and%20download%20reports) section of the [iTunes Connect Help FAQs](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq) should help with answer to your query:

> #### When will I be paid?
>
> Payments are made within 45 days of the last day of the month in which app purchases were made. To receive payment, you must have provided all required banking and tax information and documentation, as well as meeting the minimum payment threshold.
>
> If your bank and bank account currency is listed in the minimum payment threshold, you must exceed a minimum payment threshold of $10 USD. All other bank countries and bank account currencies must exceed a minimum payment threshold of $150 USD.

If you have specific concerns and queries not addresses in the [help documents](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/overview) and FAQs, you can get in touch with the [Apple Developer Support](http://developer.apple.com/contact/).